# Containers on different swarm nodes can't reach eachother

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

in short, I've got the problem that containers in a swarm can't reach containers that sit on another node. The worker node is in my home network, so not directly accessible externally.

Setup:

Manager node that is a publicly available server, let's give it the IP A.A.A.A
Worker node that is at home, behind a router, with the internal IP B.B.B.B and the router with public IP C.C.C.C

The worker can without a problem join the swarm, the manager can without problems allocate containers to that worker, so some sort of communication is established and working.
What is not working is, that containers on the manager can't reach containers on the worker and vice versa (but can reach containers on the same node)

`docker node ls` shows the worker node as `Ready` and `Active`. `docker node inspect <NODE NAME>` show the IP C.C.C.C under `Status`

minimal working example:

docker-compose

```docker
version: "3.8"
services:
  manager1:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    hostname: manager1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  manager2:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    hostname: manager2
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  worker1:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    hostname: worker1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
  worker2:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    hostname: worker2
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
```

deploying with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml testing`

`docker network inspect testing_default -v` on manager shows

```js
"Peers": [
    {
        "Name": "f0de4150d01e",
        "IP": "A.A.A.A"
    }
],
"Services": {
    "testing_manager1": {
        "VIP": "10.0.25.5",
        "Ports": [],
        "LocalLBIndex": 21646,
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "Name": "testing_manager1.1.w6b2wufu96vk1jmtez9dtewr0",
                "EndpointID": "213b7182882e267f249edc52be57f6c56d83efafeba471639f2cbb9398854fe0",
                "EndpointIP": "10.0.25.6",
                "Info": {
                    "Host IP": "A.A.A.A"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "testing_manager2": {
        "VIP": "10.0.25.8",
        "Ports": [],
        "LocalLBIndex": 21645,
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "Name": "testing_manager2.1.5w51imw8toh81oyeruu48z2pr",
                "EndpointID": "41eeb9eaf97cd3f744873ccea9577332e24c799f61171c59447e084de9c829a4",
                "EndpointIP": "10.0.25.9",
                "Info": {
                    "Host IP": "A.A.A.A"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

`docker network inspect testing_default -v` on worker shows

```js
"Peers": [
    {
        "Name": "75fba815742b",
        "IP": "B.B.B.B"
    },
    {
        "Name": "f0de4150d01e",
        "IP": "A.A.A.A"
    }
],
"Services": {
    "testing_worker1": {
        "VIP": "10.0.25.10",
        "Ports": [],
        "LocalLBIndex": 293,
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "Name": "testing_worker1.1.ol4x1h560613l7e7yqv94sj68",
                "EndpointID": "3a9dc067b4a0e7e5d26fabdcb887b823f49bfad21fc0ec159edd8dd4f976b702",
                "EndpointIP": "10.0.25.11",
                "Info": {
                    "Host IP": "B.B.B.B"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "testing_worker2": {
        "VIP": "10.0.25.2",
        "Ports": [],
        "LocalLBIndex": 292,
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "Name": "testing_worker2.1.m2d5fwn83uxg9b7udakq1o41x",
                "EndpointID": "8317415fe2b0fa77d1195d33e91fa3354fcfd00af0bab5161c69038eb8fe38bb",
                "EndpointIP": "10.0.25.3",
                "Info": {
                    "Host IP": "B.B.B.B"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So the worker sees the manager as a peer, but does not see the other services. What confuses me, is that the Host IP for worker services is B.B.B.B, which is the internal IP of the worker node (so a 192.168.x.x IP) instead of the external IP of my home network.

Attaching to one of the containers with `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> /bin/sh` and executing `wget -qO- <ANOTHER CONTAINERS IP>:8000` returns fine for containers on the same node, but Host unreachable for containers on the other node. (Testing with the defined host names returns "bad address" for the ones on the other node)

Looking at the docs, it reads at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts that there need to be some ports open.

I was under the impression that creating the swarm comes with a virtual network between the nodes (which kinda seems to be the case, as the services can get created without a problem, so there is a connection). But as it did not work like that, I tested it with just plain port forwarding, which resulted in the manager "sometimes" seeing the other services when inspecting the network, but the containers still can't reach eachother.

Am I supposed to spin up a VPN for the nodes to be inside the same network, or what am I missing?

Comment: you have to attach all services to on overlay network

Comment: The automatically created network is an overlay network, that is not the problem.

Comment: You don’t attach any service to that overlay network in the compose file

Comment: They are automatically attached to the default network. You can have a look at the code blocks above. And again: Services are able to reach services on the same node, so the network problem is not on compose level, but rather somewhere above.
If the **nodes** are on the same network everything works as expected, the problem has to be with swarm communication across network boundaries.